# What are the differences between answers

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing SQL exercises.

Question: what classrooms are the most popular

Table:

```
id int
date date
class int
number_pair int
teacher int
subject int
classroom int
```

My answer:

```
select classroom, count (classroom) as count
from Schedule
group by classroom
order by count desc
limit 2
```

Correct answer:

```
select classroom 
from Schedule
group by classroom
having count(classroom) = (select  count (classroom) as count
                           from Schedule
                           group by classroom
                           order by count desc
                           limit 1)
```

The result is the same but website tells my answer is wrong.

What am I missing? What is wrong with my query?

Any feedback would be highly appreciated =)

Comment: Your query returns 2 columns as compared to 1, which is apparent. Without input data/expected output, it will be difficult to say if queries return same output.

Comment: @shahkalpesh that's the less significant difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer will return all classrooms tied for most popular; your answer will return at most two classrooms, one of the most popular, and either another tied for most popular or a second most popular.

Nowadays, a better correct answer is

```
select classroom
from (
    select classroom, rank() over (order by count(1)) as r
    from Schedule
    group by classroom
) ranked_classrooms
where r=1
```